# Checking if .NET is installed from the command line

Tags: .net

Is there anything similar to the following in Windows that will let me know if .NET is installed from the command line?

```
$ java -version
$ ruby --version
$ python --version
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What OS and command shell are you using?

With Windows from a batch file

```
if EXIST %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v1.0.3705\mscorlib.dll
if EXIST %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v1.1.4322\mscorlib.dll
if EXIST %WINDIR%\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll
```

With Windows from PowerShell

```
if (test-path (join-path $env:windir "Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll"))){
```

Comment: The question is "if" .net is installed. Can't run powershell if it isn't.

Comment: @EBGreen, the questioner didn't specify a version.  It's possible to have powershell without all versions of the framework (v1,v1.1 and eventually v4.0).  I tried to make the answer as complete as possible.

Comment: The way that the question is worded, he just wants to determine if .net is installed at all. Any version. Now you may be right that he actually wants to know the version, but that isn't the way that the question is written.

Comment: so is it safe to assume that some version of .NET is installed if the Microsoft.Net folder is present in %WINDIR%?

Comment: It is likely, but I would say that there are potential instances where that would not be the case. For instance if someone had uninstalled it is possible that the root folder would be left behind.

Comment: Jared is right that the best bet is to check for the existence of one of a version of mscorlib.dll.

Comment: @EBGreen,@Abdullah, It's unfortunately not unrare for the framework folder to be present but not be installed.  On my Vista machine a I have the 1.0, 1.1 and 2.0 folder but only the 2.0 framework is actually installed

Answer (score 2):

You can use clrver command to check which .net frameworks are installed.

Comment: The clrver command requires Visual Studio or the Windows SDK.  [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427522.aspx)