# Creating an application (not written in .NET) to check for .NET Framework

Tags: .net, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Checking if .NET is installed from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520631/checking-if-net-is-installed-from-the-command-line)

I have a C# Windows form application that when it is opened on a computer that doesn't have .NET Framework 4 on it, it shows an error, but not a helpful one. So i wanted to make my own way of determining if the machine has .NET Framework (and show a helpful messege on how to install it) but after some research I understood that you must use a non-.Net language to do that that will encase your app. So i do not know any non .NET language so I would like your help.

If you could help me find code that will suit my needs (preferably with explanations on how to use it) it will help me a lot!

Comment: If you don't need to write your own, http://www.asoft.be/prod_netver.html works well and is free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an installer with NSIS and use [this script](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_to_insure_a_required_version_of_.NETFramework_is_installed) to automatically check for and download the .NET Framework if the specified version is not installed.  I've used NSIS like this for a couple of .NET applications that are out in the wild.

Comment: i am using InstallShield ot install my application, and i can check for .Net Framework, but what i want is, if it doesnt exist to guide the user on how to install it, maybe even a download link

Comment: @AlonMln - I'm not sure about InstallShield.  I used to write InstallShield installers and custom tasks like this were always a pain and sometimes buggy.  That's one big reason I switched to NSIS.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Windows deployment system and produce an MSI file, it will automatically check for .NET Framework on computers that are installing it.

Another solution is to use .NET Framework 1.1, since that is included with every version of Windows XP and later. Check for a folder with starting with 4_0 in Program Files/Microsoft .NET/

Comment: .NET 1.1 is *not* included with XP.  No such folder exists either.

Comment: i am currently using InstallShield to install my program, because it is the most efficient in doing it.
with what language and how can i check if .Net is installed by only using .Net 1.1?